# How to prevent a site from ever using experimental core modules?

Tags: 8, security

Quote from [Experimental modules in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/core/experimental):

> Drupal 8 core introduces the concept of experimental modules. These are modules that are provided with Drupal core for testing purposes, but that are not yet fully supported. Experimental modules are included in the Core (Experimental) package on the Extend page of a Drupal site (`/admin/modules`).

I do understand what "testing purposes" means, and I'm aware of best practices like having a ***Dev / Staging / QA / Prod*** configuration.

But when using Drupal 8 in a ***Prod*** environment, I'm looking for a way to ensure to a site owner something like "***`You can be 100% that there is no way that any of these experimental modules can ever be enabled in the prod version of your site.`***". Imagine it's about a business critical Drupal site where "testing in production" is not ever allowed.

So what options do I have in Drupal, apart from hacking core (which is not an option), to be 100% sure of this? And so that:

- It applies for "everybody" (any user), so even `user/1` should not be able to do so if (s)he'd be tempted to do so.
- It doesn't matter if you're using the Admin UI, Drush, Console or anything similar

**Update**

There are some D8 core issues about these experimental modules, which IMO are either related, or contains some inspiring comments for finding a possible solution (work around?):

- [Remove experimental modules from core (or treat them like first class modules)](https://www.drupal.org/node/2699539).
- [[meta] No definition of "Experimental" & not nearly enough warning](https://www.drupal.org/node/2649768), with proposed solutions detailed in these related issues:

  - [Experimental modules should have their own version numbers](https://www.drupal.org/node/2656994).
  - [Use a confirmation form when enabling experimental modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2663796).
  - [Provide a link to the experimental module policy in the status report warning](https://www.drupal.org/node/2657096).
  - [Warn about experimental modules on their help pages](https://www.drupal.org/node/2657178).

Comment: Just thinking loud ... how about (option 1) some highly secured GIT construction combined with some relevant 'GIT ignore' files or (option 2) something with file permission to restrict access to the crucial parts of those experimental modules (eg: all relevant *.info files) so that Drupal can't find the modules and hence are not even available for being enabled? Haven't tried it yet, but I wonder how Drupal core would react to such attempt to confuse Drupal ...

Comment: (option 3) start a petition to have them removed. Perhaps, they should only be kept in the dev versions of core and not on full releases. Based on the official [Experimental Docs](https://www.drupal.org/core/experimental) it makes no sense to me to have them in full releases.

Comment: It's the only way to get feedback on them and evolve Drupal faster. Otherwise, modules like BigPipe and Content Moderation won't get the mainstream feedback core developers are looking for in effort to improve Drupal itself to be better than it's peers. Ones that don't make the cut _are_ removed from later releases, ones that do are promoted to core status after being stablized and approved.

Comment: Hey @NoSssweat your option 3 somehow goes in the direction of some of the issues I (concurrently) added as an update to my question. Also merci for undeleting your previously deleted answer. Suggestion: how about you "un-strike" your option 1 and 2 again, and rework your answer in something like here are various options which all won't work (= your "Option 1", "Option 2", and with relevant comments below your answer included as quotes). And maybe then add your "option 3"?

Comment: @Kevin : I do understand your "only way" viewpoint. But for anybody who has some experience with business critical systems, it should be clear that you just ***D.O. N.O.T.*** test (= do experiments) in production. How would you feel if such system would be part of a plane, in which there is a risk that "somebody" would want to start such experiment ... while "you" were flying with it? Variation: there are systems for which it costs over 1,000,000 USD (or EUR?) if they are only 1 second not available ...

Comment: Then they should be relabeled as "unstable" and moved away from the core list. I don't think it should be outright removed because this seems like a straightforward UX address to correct.

Comment: @Kevin all that would do is just move the [Do Not Press The Big Red Button](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2F4ibEAnluM&feature=youtu.be&t=1m17s)

Comment: It is a bigger picture objective, not intended to be destructive.

Comment: I am a maintainer of an experimental core module.  The process to get it into core in first place is rather rigid (subject to release and framework manager review).  Code standards and patch process is not relaxed, except for some lenience as to what can go into what version (IOW, I can't do whatever I want, core committers still make the final call).  However, experimental modules can be removed from core if they do not meet their action plan (and all experimental modules have one).  The only way for new features to get into core at this point is via the Experimental process.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that things like BigPipe, IEF, and Content Moderation are important enough to the big picture for the entire Drupal community to warrant them getting in core.  If the thought was otherwise, they would just be contrib modules.

Comment: @mpdonadio I have no doubt about anything you wrote in your prior 2 comments, that's all great stuff, exciting, appreciated, etc. But my key point in this question is as in my latest comment (to Kevin).

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I think Berdir's answer sums it up nicely.  Anything production related gets tested regardless of labels.  There are experimental modules I would use in production, dev-only contrib I would use in production, and and stable modules I would never consider using even on an intranet.

Answer (score 5):

This is by far not as black and white as you make it in regards to experimental modules.

First, on a mission critical production site, you don't want to do *anything* directly on production. Completely irrelevant then if it's an experimental module or not. Any configuration change or module should be tested first. There are modules to enforce a read only configuration system for example, that's one way to approach that. One example is [Configuration Read-only mode](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_readonly), note that I have no personal experience with it.

Second, there are experimental modules and there are experimental modules. The first experimental module apart from migrate, wich is a special case anyway, was big_pipe. Which is now officially stable in 8.3. It is a module that has zero data, zero API, zero configuration, zero UI. You just enabled it and it does its thing. As such, it was perfectly fine to use it on production already and people have been doing that, myself included. **After testing it first**, like any other module/functionality. If you found a bug, you could disable it from one minute to the other, without loosing any data or critical functionality.

On the other side of that spectrum is content_moderation and anything around that. Once you start using it, it is a critical and central part of your content creation workflow, and getting rid of it again is much harder. We specifically made it so you could uninstall it, and your content that was published was still published and same for unpublished. But your workflows and metadata around that would be gone. Also upgrading is likely going to be tough from 8.2 to 8.3. That's also why we're working hard to get media_entity into core as a non-experimental module, so people have a stable API and data storage that they can rely on.

Third, the concept of experimental modules is pretty new and there's a bunch of modules in core that we would have made experimental if we could have back when they were added. rest.module and the related modules is one example there.

And last, lots of contrib modules are at least as experimental as experimental core modules, they just don't warn you about that in such an obvious way. Especially development/pre-beta versions. They just don't warn you about themself in such an obvious way.

To summarize, as with many other things, you need to do your research about an experimental module before using it, and for example check if it's big_pipe-like or content_moderation-like. And then decide what that means for your site.

Comment: Merci for this interesting answer (also)! Everything you wrote about is great stuff, exciting, etc. The phrase "***There are modules to enforce a read only configuration system for example***" is IMO the part that would probably give me the 100% assurance of what my question is about. Not to hijack your answer, but do you have specific module name(s) that you're aware of? PS: I'm not allowed to post a followup question like "which module can help me to enforce a read only config" (off topic ...).

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens "How can I have read-only configuration in production?" would be a great question, as long as it isn't an explicit module reco.  I don't recall seeing anything similar here, and I think it would be a good long term question for the site.

Comment: I added a link to the one module that I know of in the answer

Comment: Thanks for not using my module as the "other end of the spectrum" :)  Also worth noting that a contrib author can tag anything as "stable", even if it isn't or they make BC-breaks.

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure about this, but I think the only bulletproof way is to

- Extend `ModuleHandler` or implement your own `ModuleHandlerInterface` class, and exclude experimental modules from the methods.  Then replace the `@module_hander` in the service container.
- Extend `ModuleInstaller` or implement your own `ModuleInstallerInterface` class, and exclude experimental modules from the methods.  Then replace the `@module_installer` in the service container.
- Implement a `hook_system_info()` to remove experimental modules from the discovery list.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens ModuleHandler is beast of a class that is used in a lot of places.  Install/uninstall is primarily done in `ModulesListForm` ; you can look at that for uses, but also note that it directly uses `ModuleInstaller`.  https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic-services has info on swapping out services.  IEF, the Language Service, and one or two other core services use this.

Answer (score 0):

**Wanted to delete this, but going to leave this undeleted for the comments sake.**

<strike>Option 1)</strike>

Don't give client the `Administer modules` permission and don't give them user 1.

Option 2)

Custom module with hook_form_alter that loads the CSS or JS file which hides those rows.

EX:

jQuery to hide the table row that belongs to a experimental module.

```
(function ($) {

    $('tr').each(function() {

       var module_attr = $(this).attr('data-drupal-selector');

       if (module_attr == 'edit-modules-content-moderation' || 'edit-modules-datetime-range' || ...) {

         $(this).hide();

       }
    });

}(jQuery));
```

Or you can hide them all with

`$('#edit-modules-core-experimental').hide();`

or

CSS `#edit-modules-core-experimental { display: none; }`

Also add a validate function in case the client strips the CSS/JS or checkmarks the value via inspect element.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but ... Option 1 is not an option I think (user/1 can get around it). Option 2 I need to think about it ... But what about using possible work arounds like drush, etc to enable such modules then? PS: you have like at least an hour to "think" ... (Be back)

Comment: `what about using possible work arounds like drush, etc to enable such modules then?` so this is a smart client then `:p`. Regarding option 1, you don't give them user 1.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens regarding Drush, take a look at [this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188817/how-to-prevent-devel-module-to-be-installed-on-production-enviroments#answer-226386) assuming it works, then your next question is what about Drupal Console? How do you guard against being enabled by editing the mysql table? I guess the answer is, you cannot guarantee 100%.

Comment: Option 2 is just bad advice I'm sorry to say. Hiding the elements will do nothing to prevent the user from editing the values and submitting the form.

Comment: "***Don't give them user 1***" is not always an option, eg for sites where you developed it, and then turn it over entirely to someone else (eg if your contract to build a site was a work-for-hire). "***You cannot guarantee 100%***": that is exactly what I'm also thinking (which is why I posted my question) though I'd hope for some special install/CMI option soon to make it close to 100% (with some type of 4 eyes approval to change it if needed). And I somehow agree with @clive (though "bad" is probably too strong).

Comment: "Bad" isn't too strong, if anything it's too weak. Security through obscurity is worse than pointless as it gives a false sense that things are protected

Comment: @Clive that I fully agree with, but as per my ESL-problem, "bad" sounds a bit "bad" to me.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, you can make the UI safe by adding code in validate and/or submit in a form alter hook. Doesn't help of course for drush/console.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens This is English speaking site, you shouldn't be surprised to see English words here. There's no point burying your head in the sand, if something is bad, call it bad. Then less people will suffer because of it.

Comment: @4k4 merci, I thought about such hook also, but that of course requires extra precautions for things like drush/console

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, if you give a user tools like this they can do much worse than install a module.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens if you're just handing over the site to the Client, at this point, you should just teach/tell them not to enable any modules under the Experimental heading and that you have no control over those modules since they come with Core.

Comment: That doesn't really instill a lot of confidence in Drupal and the project you're delivering to the client.