# D8 can't see module

Tags: 8

Using the drupal console I created a module in a `/sites` subdirectory - because I want that module to be available only during development.

The creation process worked.

I tried to create a controller using the console and it said there was no such module. I tried enabling the module: no such module. Using:

```
drupal debug:module --type=no-core
```

listed the one other module I've created which is in `/modules`.

(Yes, I cleared caches.)

Comment: If you created a module under /sites/SITE A/modules/ then it won't display in root drupal folder. You have to go under sites/SITE A and list down modules there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only valid places for modules to live are:

- /modules
- /sites/foo_site/modules/ (modules here will only be available when you list modules for that site specifically)
- /profiles/foo_profile/modules (modules here will only be available when the site has been installed with this profile)

Anywhere else and Drupal won't find them. There's more information on the [Installing Drupal 8 Modules](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/extending-drupal-8/installing-drupal-8-modules#mod_location) page.

Disabling a module for a particular environment is something different, you handle it with configuration management rather than file system paths.

See [How to prevent devel module to be installed on production enviroments?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188817/how-to-prevent-devel-module-to-be-installed-on-production-enviroments) for the full picture.

Comment: This I know, and that's what "created a module in a /sites subdirectory" says. it's in a /sites/foo_site/modules directory.

Comment: OK. I looked it up. Got the picture.