# How to disable modules using config split?

Tags: 8, configuration

I have created different split for each environement (local, dev, test, prod) using the [Configuration Split](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_split) module. How can manage modules (enable/disable) in each environment?

Should I keep `core.extensions.yml` in each split and remove the module to be uninstalled from the list?

Answer (score 10):

The `core.extension.yml` should only be put into the default, shared config. As it only holds those modules, that are enabled across all your different environments.

```
$config_directories['sync'] = '../config/sync/default/shared';
```

This default Drupal config sync directory also has the `config_split.config_split.local.yml` in it, which defines which modules apart from the ones in the `core.extension.yml` should be enabled additionally when the `local` split is active.

```
uuid: abc123456-7890-abcd-906d-abc123456
langcode: en
status: false
dependencies: {  }
id: local
label: Local
folder: ../config/sync/default/local
module:
  browsersync: 0
  devel: 0
  features_ui: 0
  field_ui: 0
  kint: 0
  link_css: 0
  masquerade: 0
  views_ui: 0
  webprofiler: 0
theme: {  }
blacklist: {  }
graylist: {  }
graylist_dependents: true
graylist_skip_equal: true
weight: 0
```

Then, inside each environment's `settings.local.php` you have to define which split in addition to the default, shared config should be active and which not. Here's how it may be configured on your local machine:

```
$config['config_split.config_split.local']['status'] = TRUE;
$config['config_split.config_split.dev']['status']   = FALSE;
$config['config_split.config_split.stage']['status'] = FALSE;
$config['config_split.config_split.prod']['status']  = FALSE;
```

---

The `core.extension.yml` only holds those modules that are shared among **all** your different environments.

Comment: This. It's critical to have every environment covered in your settings.php (or settings.local.php) like @leymannx has shown above. Some tutorials have shown where if production is set as the default configuration, a specific configuration split isn't needed, but in my tests, I haven't been able to get that to work.

Comment: When making changes to settings*php files and/or config like this. Remember to `drush cache:rebuild` if something isn't making sense. I often have to do this for config:import to pick up the changes I just made on disk. Even after that, I sometimes have to go to /admin/config/development/configuration/config-split to make sure the right environment is showing. And after a cache:rebuild even that page takes a reload (load up some cache?) to get the environment switched. Just play with it.

Comment: Took me a bit to figure out since I was trying to turn off a module from prod locally. The modules must be disabled in core.extension.yml and then you let config_split.config_split.prod.yml enable them. If you have them enabled in core.extension.yml it won't work as expected.