# How can I avoid saved configuration settings to be exported?

Tags: 8, configuration

I have a custom module and I added a form that allows the administrator to save some settings. Now, when I export the configuration (`drush cex`), I notice that these settings are being exported to a file (mymodule.settings.yml in the config directory).

I don't want to export these settings. How can I avoid it?

Comment: Why do you not want to export it? If it's site specific, then yes, state might be an option. If it's sensitive data, see also http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185536/exclude-configuration-from-import-export?rq=1

Comment: @Berdir it is environment specific (each dev and production instance will have different values) and also there is a token which can change sometimes in the future.

Comment: Yes, I'd still use configuration and local settings overrides, as described in my link, so you never have the productive settings in the database. State is just a simple API to store values in the key_value table. So if you for example copy your production site to staging, you will overwrite the existing values there with your production configuration. $settings-based overrides will make sure that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to export configuration you should use [State API](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/state).
From documentation:

> - It is specific to an individual environment.
> - **You will never want to deploy it between environments.**
> - You can reset a system, losing all state. Its configuration remains.

Comment: You're right, State API is what I need here. I am not sure if getEditableConfigNames function should also be changed (it returns an array with a single value that was used for $this->config('THE-VALUE') but now I don't use anywhere). Maybe getEditableConfigNames should now return an empty array? Anyway, it is working, thanks..