# How can I prevent some configuration settings getting overwritten?

Tags: 8, drush, configuration

I tell drush this:

```
drush @live cim --skip-modules=system,swiftmailer
```

and Drush replies with this:

```
  Collection  Config                 Operation                
              swiftmailer.transport  update 
              system.performance     update
  Import the listed configuration changes? (y/n)
```

and, if I reply "y", the settings in the live Drupal site are overwritten from settings previously exported from the dev system.

What do I have to do to avoid importing selected parts of an exported configuration?

Comment: Same question as http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185536/exclude-configuration-from-import-export?rq=1

Comment: Does this mean that `--skip-modules` is redundant/ defective?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude configuration from import/export](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185536/exclude-configuration-from-import-export)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that [Config Ignore](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_ignore) could help you out here.

Spoiler: I am the maintainer of that module.

Install the module, go to `admin/config/development/configuration/ignore` and add the names of the config entities that you would like to **not to change**, when you import.

In this case:

```
swiftmailer.transport
system.performance
```

Save, remember to export `config_ignore.settings.yml` to the config folder (yes, some of us tend to forget that bit) and you should be golden.

Comment: Thanks. Will look into that. BTW do you exactly what `--skip-modules` is supposed to do?

Comment: `--skip-modules` is broken. A lot.

I was actually told a few days ago that there is being work done on a more reliable/stable version of how to exclude configuration when using Drush, but I can't point you toward any specific issue that will prove this. Sorry.