# Prevent block config from being exported?

Tags: 8, configuration

In Drupal 8, how can I prevent block instance config from being exported? I want it to just be ignored.

Comment: Have you already tried to do that with [Config Ignore](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_ignore)? I don't remember right now how fine grainable it was and if you not even could pass wildcards for really certain values like for block instances to it.

Comment: Another starting point would be https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/marcus_w/config_ignore_custom_blocks, but I can't properly check it out right now, on mobile.

Comment: Ah yeah, and there's Drush CMI Tools with a `config-ignore.yml` which we eventually used for exactly that. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/236088/15055

Comment: Just for clarification, why exactly would you need this feature? You let editors access the blocks config page???

Comment: It makes deployments and updates hard when content is actively made (this project allows blocks to be made for sidebar content) because CMI will try to delete the block configs that are not in config but are in the database. Figured I would just eliminate that tracking.

Comment: @Kevin : How do you perform the updates/deployments? Asking this since an answer to this question could be tool specific.

Comment: Config import... no additional modules. Blocks are the only pain point.

Comment: I was thinking of drush's `cim --partial` option, that's why I talked about tools. I assume then, you use the web interface for config import?

Comment: No. Drush to import.

Comment: Have you checked the `--partial` option already then? Or, is there more to it than ".. because CMI will try to delete the block configs that are not in config but are in the database". Cheers!

Comment: It also doesn't do the inverse does it? If they delete blocks, then it will try to create them again.

Comment: That's true. In that case, config_ignore is your best bet I would say. Have you had a go at that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude configuration from import/export](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185536/exclude-configuration-from-import-export)